# User permissions running a LAMP stack on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I am currently running Apache, MySQL and PHP 7.2 on CentOS 7.

My web directory is `/var/www/html`.

Now the issue is that there is one SFTP account which is root and has access to all directories. When a file is uploaded to the website directory the user is root and the group apache.

So I need to change the user to apache with:

```
sudo chown -R apache /var/www/html/
```

Then the user is Apache and I can edit the file with my web software which uses PHP.

I was told that the user will always be root when files are uploaded by root via SFTP.

Is there a way of making it so that when files are uploaded by my SFTP account that they are editable without doing the sudo chown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the user be changed automatically cannot be done on Linux - it would potentially cause a "[file giveaway](https://superuser.com/a/472364/110559)" problem where the user who created the file cannot edit the file because it was automatically changed to be owned by a different user.

The easiest solution is to use [`setgid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_a_directory) (via `chmod g+s`) on the parent directory to make the uploaded files belong to a group which the `apache` user is a member of and to set a [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) (via `umask 0002`, or similar) which makes sure that the new files always have group write permission. Then Apache (and PHP) will be able to modify them.

(Note that the fact that your files are already uploaded with the `apache` group suggests that you are already halfway there - i.e. you already have the `setgid` bit set.)

For more about these commands, you can see the SuperUser Blog post [Linux Permissions Demystified](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/).

Comment: Thanks for you information. This makes sense. I do remember using setgid. But makes sense to set the umask as mentioned in your post. I'll test it later when I get home. Thanks for this.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this yet but I am sure it will work. I have just checked and my umask is 0022 which from what I understand is read only which is why I was having the trouble. I use find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \; to setgid and umask 0002 and hopefully that will fix my problem. I have to remember these configurations for future VPS instances.